# Error while trying to use dynamic routing to pass variables to the template and using them

Tags: filter, entry-type, routing, error-templates

So i'm trying to pass the variables from a dynamic route to a template and then to use those variables to filter trough entries.
the catch is that the same template is used to display an "organic"(by organic i mean that it is set up from the CP) category as well.

This is the routes.php

```
'shop/(?P<segmentCategory>(new|used))/(?P<segmentEntryType>[a-z]+)' => 'shop/category',
```

And this is from the template:

```
{% if segmentCategory is defined %}
    {% set category = craft.categories(segmentCategory) %}
    {% set games = craft.entries({
        type: segmentEntryType,
        relatedTo: ['and',
            { sourceElement: craft.entries.section(segmentEntryType).status(null) },
            { targetElement: category }
        ]
    }) %}
{% else %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}
{% endif %}
```

The error:

```
    Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string
```

craft/templates/shop/category.html(47)

```
47 {% extends "_layout" %} ||||||||||||||(Highlighted)||||||||||||||||
48 {% block content %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% set category = craft.categories(segmentCategory).first %}
```

Without the `first` at the end, you're setting `category` to an ElementCriteriaModel. Which would be fine in many cases, but it's not an [acceptable variable type](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) for `targetElement`.

Ditto for the `sourceElement`:

```
craft.entries.section(segmentEntryType).status(null).first
```

Comment: It fixed the error but now for some reason it doesn't filter the content... and the conditional `{% if not entries %}` never returns true

Comment: Great! I'd say to post that as a separate question, but it looks like you [already have...](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/10859/45) :)