# Looping through returns nothing after using dynamic routes to get the entry type and category

Tags: categories, routes, entry-type, forloop, entrymodel

I'll explain a bit of the structure of the content and then proceed to the issue.

So i have a website with a shop in it with the url mysite.com/shop/,
it is an channel section, and its template is located at craft/templates/shop/index.html.

The shop is divided in to 2 categories - "new", and "used",
the url for each is mysite.com/shop/(used or new), and its template is located at craft/templates/shop/category.html.

The section(channel) shop that is mentioned above also has multiple entry types, for example "televisions", "consoles", "computers"... and each one has a required category field to chose one of the above(new or used), and the url for those entries is 'shop/{condition.first().slug}/{type}/{slug}'
(the condition field is the category).

Now to what i'm trying to do, and whats the issue.
I want the user to be able to filter through entry types within the category template. what i mean is that te used could click "show only tv's"
and a url with the new filter will load but with the same template, so the url would look like that:
mysite.com/shop/used/television/

To accomplish that i've made a new dynamic route by adding the nex line to my routes.php:
`'shop/(?P<segmentCategory>(new|used))/(?P<segmentEntryType>[a-z]+)' => 'shop/category',`

And the template goes like this(the twig part only):

```
{% if segmentCategory is defined %}
    {% set category = craft.categories.slug(segmentCategory).first() %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries({
        type: segmentEntryType,
        relatedTo: ['and',
            { sourceElement: category },
            { targetElement: craft.entries.type(segmentEntryType).status(null).first }
        ]
    }) %}
    {% if not entries %}
        {% exit 404 %}
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}
{% endif %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% else %}
    There are no entries matching you criteria right no, please try again in a few days.
{% endfor %}
```

I'm having two issues with this code.

**First:** `{% if not entries %}` never executes, even if i enter complete nonsense in the url.
**Second:** the array `entries` is never outputs anything...

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 4):

> `{% if not entries %}` never executes, even if i enter complete nonsense in the url.

You’re not ensuring that `segmentCategory` is a valid category slug anywhere. If it’s not, then `category` will get set to `null`, which will basically prevent it from affecting the following `relatedTo` param.

So right after grabbing the `category` you should make sure it exists;

```
{% set category = craft.categories.slug(segmentCategory).first() %}
{% if not category %}
  {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}
```

> the array entries is never outputs anything

I think this is because your `relatedTo` parameter isn’t set up correctly. If the used/new categories are being assigned to the entries via a Categories field on the entry, then the category should be set to the `targetElement` property, not `sourceElement`, since the category is the *target* element of the relation. And you can just get rid of the current `targetElement` stuff, which should have been `sourceElement`, but is redundant and doesn’t need to be specified anyway.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    type: segmentEntryType,
    relatedTo: { targetElement: category }
}) %}
```

> Ok, now i get the posts, but if i pass an invalid string to the segmentEntryType the template still loads.

This conditional:

```
{% if not entries %}
```

should be:

```
{% if not entries|length %}
```

(At this point in your template, `entries` will be a defined ElementCriteriaModel regardless of whether it matches any entries. Including the `length` filter in your conditional will force it to execute the DB query and return the actual results.)

Comment: Ok, now i get the posts, but if i pass an invalid string to the `segmentEntryType` the template still loads.

Comment: @SamuelElgozi Just updated my answer to address that.

Comment: First thank you, and that does redirect me to the 404 page. the problem is that even if the entry type exists but has no entries i get redirected. (sorry for making it complicated), i've opened [another question for that](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10872/checking-if-a-value-matches-an-entry-type-handle).