# Checking if a value matches an entry type handle

Tags: error-message, entry-type, array, segments

I am trying to check if a value provided by the user (url segment) matches an entry type, and if not redirect to 404.

```
{% set section = craft.sections.getSectionByHandle('shop') %}
{% set entryTypes = section.getEntryTypes('handle') %}
{% if not segmentEntryType in entryTypes|keys %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}
```

`segmentEntryType` is the string from the segment.
i get the error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Node "1" does not exist for Node "Twig_Node".").
```

Comment: You need to specify what the entry type are (unless you are getting the entry type "handle")

Comment: How can i get a list of the entry type's handels?

Comment: If you go to settings->sections, that will show a list of all section and their handles. if you then click on edit entry type for a section (a channel section) it should give you a list of entry types and their handles.

Comment: No, what i mean is that how can i put a list of the existing entry type's handles so i can check if `segmentEntryType` matches one of them, and if it desn't redirect to 404 page. thats what i'm trying to do.

Comment: {% set entryTypes = section.getEntryTypes() %} should return an array of entryTypes

Comment: you could loop over entryTypes and output them to see what you have i fin doubt.